# restricting DISTINCT in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I want to get the name, the surname and place of birth from a certain graph. I get results like "John" "Doe" "London" and "John" "Doe" "UK" . Is there a way to restrict and express somehow the DISTINCT in only the 2 (name and surname?) out of 3 (name, surname and birthplace) ?

Comment: [RobV's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21502162/1281433) is correct here.  It uses `sample`, but if you have some preference about whether you get `London` or `UK`, you might be able to achieve it using a different aggregate function.  You could even combine the strings with concatenation, e.g., `"London, UK"` (though the order might be hard guarantee). `group by` plus an aggregate function sounds like what you need, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't shown any example data or queries you've tried which makes this question harder to answer, please include those details in future.

One approach is to use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT` e.g.

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?name ?surname (SAMPLE(?loc) AS ?location)
WHERE
{
  ?person foaf:givenName ?name ;
          foaf:familyName ?surname ;
          foaf:based_near ?loc .
}
GROUP BY ?name ?surname
```

This query groups your results together by `?name` and `?surname` and selects one of the possible locations for each group of results.

The `SAMPLE()` aggregate used here basically asks the query engine to select one possible value for a non-group key variable from the grouped results.